# Issue with spring boot integration test in intellij ( mvn clean test works )

Tags: spring, intellij-idea, spring-boot, yaml

so..

I have an integration test which runs without any issues from terminal using `mvn clean test` - so its rather issue with IDE not code itself.

Intellij Idea version: **14.1.4**, build: **141.1532**

Running from intellij cause exception:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml.<init>(Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/constructor/BaseConstructor;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/representer/Representer;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/DumperOptions;Lorg/yaml/snakeyaml/resolver/Resolver;)V
at org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader$Processor.createYaml(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:85)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlProcessor.process(YamlProcessor.java:136)
at org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader$Processor.process(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:100)
at org.springframework.boot.env.YamlPropertySourceLoader.load(YamlPropertySourceLoader.java:57)
at org.springframework.boot.env.PropertySourcesLoader.load(PropertySourcesLoader.java:126)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.loadIntoGroup(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:381)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:369)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener$Loader.load(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:339)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.addPropertySources(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:174)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:144)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:137)
at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(ConfigFileApplicationListener.java:126)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:151)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:128)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.publishEvent(EventPublishingRunListener.java:100)
at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:59)
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:285)
at org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader.loadContext(SpringApplicationContextLoader.java:101)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:68)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:86)
at org.springframework.test.context.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:117)
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:212)
at org.springframework.test.context.testng.AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.springTestContextPrepareTestInstance(AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests.java:145)
```

any ideas?

Comment: Looks like some strange dependency conflict. You could use a [Maven Helper](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179?pr=idea_ce) plugin to help you resolve it. If you can create a quickstart, then report a bug on IntelliJ.

Comment: Do you have any provided dependencies by any chance? These are not taken into account by IJ (there are several bugs in their tracker about that)

Comment: maven helper found some conflicts, but resolving them changed nothing (but thank you for pointing out this plugin). I dont have any provided dependencies. I will try to set up minimal project and post bug.

Comment: did you get any resolution? i have the exact same error. project was working fine until just the other day... !!

Comment: yep, errors like these are pain in the... IIRC I just downloaded this snakeyaml (whatever it is) on disk and add it in 'Project structure' as library, because nothing else worked. Do you have your intellij updated? Maybe its fixed in recent version?